# Font Awsome icons not displaying in Android

Tags: android, font-awesome, nativescript-angular

I want to use some fa icons for nativescript tabview instead of title name so :
*tabItem="{title: ''}. I import the ttf file te fonts directory, add the class to app.css and the class name to template but still i get a "x" instead of the icon. Seen a lot of tutorials but still no change. Is there anything else to do?

Template :

```
<TabView androidSelectedTabHighlightColor="blue" id="tview" backgroundColor="gray" androidTabsPosition="bottom" #tabView (selectedIndexChanged)="tabIndexChanged($event)" (swipe)="onSwipe($event)">

    <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: '&#xe913;'}" class="fa">
        <home-tab></home-tab>
    </StackLayout>

    <StackLayout *tabItem="{title: 'Configuration'}" class="fa">
        <configuration-tab></configuration-tab>
    </StackLayout>

</TabView>
```

app.css:

```
.fa { 
    font-family: 'FontAwesome', fontawesome-webfont
}
```

Comment: Sharing your code with us ?

Comment: already did @ThomasMary, thnx for reply

Comment: is it possible for you to create a playground?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this library from Mikepenz https://github.com/mikepenz/Android-Iconics.